# Cinemachine FreeLookCam stays in "bottom rig" and won't switch to other rigs

Tags: unity, 3d, mobile, cinemachine

I have an issue with Cinemachine. I set it up to follow and look at the "player," and I added the script recommended by another user:

```cs
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(CinemachineFreeLook))]
public class FreeLookUserInput : MonoBehaviour {

    private CinemachineFreeLook freeLookCam;

    void Start () {
        freeLookCam = GetComponent<CinemachineFreeLook>();
    }

    void Update () {
        freeLookCam.m_XAxis.Value = Input.GetAxis("Right Stick X");
        freeLookCam.m_YAxis.Value = Input.GetAxis("Right Stick Y");
    }
}
```

While I changed the "input" to "SimpleInput" because I'm using it, the problem I can't seem to solve is that when I activate the script, the camera bugs out and stays in the "bottom rig," not allowing me to switch to the other two rigs. I would like to know if anyone knows why this is happening and how I can fix it.

In summary, I need to configure Cinemachine on the secondary joystick to move the camera in any direction while it's locked onto the player.